# Gremlin, including vertices with zero edges

Tags: orientdb, gremlin

let's say you have the following relationship:

```
Author-----wrote---->Article
```

and you want to prepare a report about each author and how many articles he has wrote and the date of his last article, the proplem appears when there are authors who wrote no articles, they will be dropped when you pass the 'wrote' pipe and i want to include them with '0' in 'count' column and 'N/A' in 'date' column, so my quesion is how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are still working with TinkerPop 2.x given your usage of OrientDB so I will answer in that fashion.  You need to do something like:

```
gremlin> g = new TinkerGraph()                        
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> bill = g.addVertex([author:'bill',type:'author'])
==>v[0]
gremlin> amy = g.addVertex([author:'amy',type:'author'])  
==>v[1]
gremlin> book1 = g.addVertex([book:1,type:'book'])        
==>v[2]
gremlin> book2 = g.addVertex([book:2,type:'book'])        
==>v[3]
gremlin> bill.addEdge('wrote',book1)                      
==>e[4][0-wrote->2]
gremlin> bill.addEdge('wrote',book2)
==>e[5][0-wrote->3]
gremlin> g.V.has('type','author').transform{[it, it.outE('wrote').count()]}
==>[v[0], 2]
==>[v[1], 0]
```

Comment: I found another solution, I used 'copySplit' pipe to split the pipe into 2 pipes, one that gets the vertices with no edges and the other gets the vertices with one or more then merged them, but I think your answer is better, since I  think that in copy split pipe, each vertex is revisited for each copied pipe, am I right about this assumption?

Comment: yes - that's correct, plus `copySplit` doesn't always work well in TinkerPop 2.x.  `union` step in 3.x works much better however: http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-incubating/#union-step